# Difference between Site Collection Owners and Secondary Owners in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Can anyone help me to find the difference between Site Collection Owners and Secondary Owners in SharePoint Server 2010.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a difference - both have the same permissions.  It is just an option presented to you to ensure that there is a secondary contact/user that is responsible for site collection management.